# Android Studios: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types

Tags: kotlin

Having an error with Android Studios (Kotlin)

Error:

> e: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

```kotlin
fun devId(): Any {
    var str = Build.CPU_ABI
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        var i = 0
        val hashSet = HashSet(listOf(arrayOf("armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64")))
        val strArr = Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS
        val length = strArr.size
        while (true) {
            if (i >= length) { break }
            val str2 = strArr[i]
            if (hashSet.contains(str2)) {
                str = str2
                break
            }
            i++
        }
    }
    return println(Build.BOARD + Build.BRAND + str + Build.DEVICE + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL + Build.PRODUCT)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `hashSet.contains(str2)`. This expression is always false. Because `hashSet` type is `HashSet<Array<String>>` but `str2` is `String` You could pass to function `contains` only `Array<String>`

Looks like you could rewrite yours code as:

```
fun devId() {
    val str = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS
            .firstOrNull { it in setOf("armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64") }
            ?: Build.CPU_ABI
    } else Build.CPU_ABI

    return println(Build.BOARD + Build.BRAND + str + Build.DEVICE + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL + Build.PRODUCT)
}
```

Comment: How do I approach this?